# A game of Chess - Ideal Solution

Tags: group-theory, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I am a student of physics. I have learnt some basic group theory, and I am wondering if there is any ideal solution for a given Chess game (like solving Rubik's cube). I know the no. of permutations are enormous that computation becomes almost impossible to do such a thing. But I am interested in knowing if there is any **Group theory based solution** being researched and developed.

Comment: I don't think group theory is very applicable because not all of the moves in chess are invertible like they are for a Rubik's cube.

Comment: No clue what a group theory solution is but Chess is solvable by Zermelo's algorithm. Too bad we will never have computational power to apply it and know what is the solution...

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that through ! Thanks !!

Comment: You may want to read Christian Ewerhart's articles (2000 and 2002) on *Games and Economic Behavior*, both articles are on the game of chess.

Comment: As pointed out, chess will never be solved mathematically. However, by incorporating intelligent positional evaluation, opening books and endgame tablebases, modern day engines would be able to crush deep blue and older supercomputers even though they have much less processing power.

Comment: @Daniel Not to all of chess, but certain contrived endgames/chess puzzles have solutions based on combinatorial game theory, which involves groups  (see [Noam Elkies' paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9905198)). In this context, the inverse of a game *position* (or a component of one) is the same position with Black and White switched.

Comment: @MarkS. I'm not too familiar with CGT so please correct me if I say something obviously wrong, however the paper you linked doesn't seem to involve any group theory or abstract algebra (I skimmed the first few pages). The fact that there is a $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ action on the space of game positions seems like a fairly vague connection.

Comment: @DanielRust Whether "group theory" is used is arguable, but Elkies identifies boards/chunks of boards with elements of the abelian group of short Games, and adds them (see, for example, the sole occurrence of the word "total" in the paper). I mentioned the inverse just as a response to "[groups are] not applicable because moves aren't invertible".

Comment: @MarkS. : Thanks for that info !!!

Answer (score 3):

For games like checkers, yes this has been solved using computers - you can guarantee at least a tie; however, for chess, there are far too many moves to be solved at this point in time because the number of strategies that must be calculated go up exponentially. It IS possible to solve it using game theory, but it is far too complicated to be done with current technology levels.

Comment: "with current technology levels." or future as well...

Comment: @SergioParreiras Can you recommend a source? Exponential technological growth as well as emerging technologies (quantum, organic computers for example) seems to guarantee that power will come

Comment: While this answer is factually correct, I do not think it really satisfies the condition that the OP has put in the question, which are the particular applications of group theory to the potential solution of chess.

Comment: @DavidPeterson: maybe with new algorithms but if we use force brute (i.e. Zermelo's algorithm), the Handbook of Game Theory (vol I, I think) has a chapter on Chess where they say the game tree of chess has an order or magnitude higher than the number of electrons in the universe (I don't know much physics so I have no clue how can we estimate the later). If this is true, we will never have enough memory to input the game tree (all possible moves). Sorry for the long comment...

Comment: @DanielRust: Why don't you post your comment as an answer instead of ...

Comment: @SergioParreiras because I don't think it constitutes an answer. It's possible that someone working in the crossover of algebra and game theory could offer a definitive answer which I can not. It's only an uninformed hunch that group theory might not be very applicable, at least not in the same way that it informs us of the solutions of the Rubik's cube.

Comment: @SergioParreiras If thats true (I haven't read the source, but I will add that to my list of things I need to read), it would indeed be probably too difficult to overcome. I worded it that way because we don't have the technology now, but what we do have now seemed impossible 100 (or even 20) years ago. The key part of what I was trying to say was, "Yes, but no" :)